# Jquery each() Counter

Tags: jquery

I've done some searching around the documentation, and spent a while on the net but cannot find a solution to this! I want the alert to tell me which iteration of each() it was on when the .thumb is clicked.

EG: There are six .thumb's I click on number 3, the browser pops-up 3!

What actually happens is regardless of which .thumb is clicked, 6 pops up.

```
var counter = 1;
$('.thumb').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        alert (counter);
    });
    counter++;
});
```

Any help is gratefully received.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

That's because you're sharing the same `counter` variable for *all* `click` handlers and it is whatever it ends up being at the end of the loop.  Instead, use the one passed into the loop (the index parameter of the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) that's already there), like this:

```
$('.thumb').each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        alert (i+1); //index starts with 0, so add 1 if you want 1 first
    });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5h7sY/).

Answer (score 0):

To use a solution like @Paulo suggested, you would need to do so like this:

```
var list = $('.thumb');

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    (function( i_local ) {
        list.eq( i ).click(function(){
            alert(i_local);
        });
    })( i + 1 );
}​
```

...although I'd [use @Nicks `.each()` solution instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929465/jquery-each-counter/3929474#3929474). Much cleaner.